# I want to move my pages numbering from top right corner to bottom center of pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

Please direct me on how to move the pages numbering of my work from the top right corners to the bottom center.
Here is a sample of my work

[image: page sample]

Here's my main code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mytherm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.10,0.00,1.00}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    frame=none
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please make your code complete, i.e. `\begin{document}` ... Some chapters text ... `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you have in the headers on even pages?

Comment: Your "main code" is basically your preamble. Please add an MWE.

Comment: Do you know the package `fancyhadr`? That package allows you to define your own headers and footers. `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` places the page number in de center of the footer.

Comment: In your preamble you load the package `amsmath` twice. Once with an option `[cmex10]`, the other one following the first one without option. That latter one will take precedence about the way the way `amsmath` is loaded: so without options!

Comment: The easy solution is to use `\pagestyle{plain}`, but you lose the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the package `fancyhdr`. It would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Centered pagenumber on the bottom. ("\cfoot{\thepage}" is deprecated.)
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark} % This prints the chapter in the head. You might customize it, like "\textsc{\leftmark}".
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{} % Empty argument, so that only the chapter is in the title. With "\rightmark" there would be the section.
% "RE" = right on even pagenumbers
% "RO" = right on odd pagenumbers
% "LE" = left on even pagenumbers
% "LO" = left on odd pagenumbers

\begin{document}

The pagenumber is now centered on the bottom of the page.

\end{document}
```

You might customize your page even further with this package. But this should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've encountered another problem using your suggestion. The headers have titles of "sections" on the LHS and "Chapters" on the RHS. Lengthy texts in these titles make the headers overlap and look improper. I would prefer to have only Chapter titles on the header please. Any suggestion on how to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my example: Now there are the chaptertitles in the head, without the sections.
I looked up "cfoot" because of the example from @miltos , who used "fancyhead[C]". The latter is correct, "cfoot" is deprecated (but still works fine in the document I work with).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsc{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've encountered another problem using your suggestion. The headers have titles of "sections" on the LHS and "Chapters" on the RHS. Lengthy texts in these titles make the headers overlap and look improper. I would prefer to have only Chapter titles on the header please. Any suggestion on how to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ekong. I modified the code so you have the Chapter title in header pages for even and odd pages. You can also have a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310260/retrieve-only-chapter-name-in-fancyhdr